# Is it Possible to create a export default function as a currying function?

Tags: ecmascript-6, currying, es6-modules

This might be a silly question but I can't find the answer to this anywhere at the minute, but is it possible to create a exported default function as a curried function?

Currently I am implementing this as follows:

```
export const switchcase = cases => defaultCase => key =>
  key in cases ? cases[key] : defaultCase;
```

But is there a way to do this in a default function? the function being:

```
export default function(cases) {}
```

Thanks

Comment: Hmm, how does export affect what you are exporting? Why do you need `default` export to be a function (not an arrow function)? And of course you could return a function from a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do

```
export default cases => defaultCase => key =>
  key in cases ? cases[key] : defaultCase;
```

or

```
export default function (cases) {
  return function (defaultCase) {
    return function (key) {
      return key in cases ? cases[key] : defaultCase;
    };
  };
}
```

or

```
const switchcase = cases => defaultCase => key =>
  key in cases ? cases[key] : defaultCase;

export default switchcase
```

Comment: Thanks for this, perfect answer!

Comment: @ChristopherJenks Glad I could help :)